# kubectl edit deployment not working but kubectl apply is working while setting up resource req/limit on deployment

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-deployment

I am trying to add resource request and limit on an existing deployment. 
when I do `kubectl edit deployment deployment_name_here`, edit the yaml and save and exit, it give me this  : `Edit cancelled, no changes made.`

but when I edit the yaml,that I used to create that deployment and add the resource details,  and do `kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml` it works.

Why this is happening? Is there any way I can do it directly using `kubectl edit ...`

Comment: Please can you post an example of a deployed yaml and what are you trying to change? With you example I can try to reproduce your problem on my cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Things like this are most likely caused by it opening an editor that forks off instead of staying.

That means you'll want to set $EDITOR to an editor that does wait. E.g. nano, vim or emacs should work.

Comment: Its set to vim.